# How to use mysqli_real_escape_string() in PHP to escape all characters except newline?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a text input which can contain special chars that needs to be escaped. But I also want to preserve the newlines. Using PHP's mysql_real_escape_string(), how is it possible to ignore the newline ('\n') from escaping.

From the official [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) of PHP on `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr ) : string
```

> escapestr: The string to be escaped.
>
> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

How is it possible to omit the `\n` from this list but keeping the others intact?

Comment: If you're inserting data into a database, better use a prepared statement, and a different function (regex? `str_replace()`?) for filtering your data. But if you really insist on using this function, just re-create the `$escapestr` without the `\n`?

Comment: _“But I also want to preserve the newlines”_ - and what do you think this had to do with `mysqli_real_escape_string` …? This function does not “eat” newlines, it just escapes them so they are safe to use within a query. This does not affect your _data_ to begin with.

Comment: @04FS to clarify: by "preserve" I meant how to not escape or exclude the newline char from mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: But _why_? You either want to let this function do its job, and take care of characters that require it … or you want something else. If preparing something to be inserted into a database query is the purpose here, then your requirement seems to make little sense, and if the purpose is _anything else_, then you’d rather be using the wrong function to begin with. So, which is it …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:
You can achieve this by:

- Explode your string to array using `\n`.
- Loop the array and have each item escaped.
- Put them back using Implode and `\n` as glue.

Code:

```
<?php
  $array = explode('\n',$stringToEscape);
  $index = 0;
  foreach($array as $string){
   $array[$index] = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link , $string) ;
   $index++;
  }
  $excapedString = implode('\n',$array);
?>
```

Solution 2:
Another solution:

- Replace `\n` with some text (e.g #*NEWLINE*#).
- Do the string escape.
- Replace the text from step 1 to `\n`.

Code:

```
<?php
 $string = '##YOUR STRING TO BE ESCAPED##';
 $stringToEscape = str_replace('\n','#_NEWLINE_#',$string);
 $escapedString = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link , $stringToEscape ) ;
 $finalString = str_replace('#_NEWLINE_#','\n',$escapedString);
?>
```

Comment: Clever, simple solutions. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom escape function like this one:

```html
function my_escape_function($value)
{
    $search = array("\\",  "\x00", "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a");
    $replace = array("\\\\","\\0", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z");

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}
```